# JavaScript and Check Boxes not working

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Basically I am trying to make a form in HTML that uses JavaScript to take input from check boxes and open a specific page on my site depending on which boxes are checked.

When I check a box or don't check a box or more it only responds by giving the alert please check a box. Does anyone have any idea on what I am missing? This is currently how I am writing the code after trying multiple different ways. Also note that I have in the same folder html pages for the specified windows I am trying to open.

JavaScript:

```
function checking()
{
    var frm = document.diaglab;
    var majdep1 = document.getElementById("majdep").checked;
    var bipolar1 = document.getElementsByName("bipolar").checked;

    if(majdep1.checked == true && bipolar1.checked == true)
    {
        window.alert("possible bipolar disorder");
        window.open("bipolar1.html");
    }else{
        window.alert("please check boxes");
    }
}
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta name="" content="">
<link href="illness.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="checked.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div >
    <h1 id="mainhead">Exploring Symptoms</h1>
</div>
<div>
    <article ><p>This exploring area is just a lab tool that allows you too explore how mental illness is diagnosed<br />
    according to the DSM V. You can click on certain symptoms and see what diagnoses may be applied. It<br />
    is important to know that this is not an actual diagnosis tool and should not be applied to your life in any<br />
    way as to self diagnose, treat or medicate yourself or anyone else. If you feel that you may be suffering<br />
    from a mental illness contact your physician! Also note that this tool is not all inclusive and if you want<br />
     a deeper understanding please refer to the DSM V.</p></article>
</div>
<hr>

<div id="explrfrm">
    <form name="diaglab"  method="post" onsubmit="return checking()">
    <label id="explrlab">Depressive and Manic Symptoms</label><br />
    <span id="explrlab1">
        <label id= title="Symptom1" >1. Depressed mood (sad, empty, hopeless)most of the day, nearly everyday.</label> <input type="checkbox" name="majdep" id="majdep" ><br /><br />
        <label  title="Symptom2">2. Diminished interest or pleasure in all or nearly all activities</label> <input type="checkbox" name="majdep" id="majdep"><br /><br />
        <label  title="Symptom3">3. Significant weight loss or gain (without dieting) or decreased appetite most days.</label> <input type="checkbox" name="majdep" id="majdep"><br /><br />
        <label  title="Symptom4">4. Insomnia (inability to sleep) or Hypersomnia (sleeping too much) nearly everyday</label> <input type="checkbox" name="majdep" id="majdep"><br /><br />
        <label title="Symptom5">5. Fatigue or loss of energy almost everyday</label> <input type="checkbox" name="majdep" id="majdep"><br /><br />
        <label  title="Symptom6">6. Feelings of worthlessness or excessive and inappropriate guilt.</label> <input type="checkbox" name="majdep" is="majdep"><br /><br />
        <label  title="Symptom7">7. Diminished ability to think, concentrate, or indecisiveness.</label> <input type="checkbox" name="majdep" id="majdep"><br /><br />
        <label  title="Symptom8">8. Recurrent thoughts of death, suicidal ideations with or without a plan and or attempt.</label> <input type="checkbox" name="majdep" id="majdep"><br /><br />
        <label  title="Symptom9">9. significant impairment  in social , occupational, or other important areas of functioning</label> <input type="checkbox" name="majdep" id="majdep"><br /><br />
        <label title="Symptom10">10. Distinct period of abnormally or persistent elevated, expansive, or irritable mood and increased goal directed energy for at least one week all day or nearly all day</label> <input type="checkbox" name="bipolar" id="bipolar"><br /><br />
        <label  title="Symptom11">11. During the period of increased mood energy at least three of the following: inflated self esteem, dcreased need for sleep, extreme talkitivity, flight of ideas,distractibility, increased goal directed activity, or excessive activity involvement nearly everyday.</label> <input type="checkbox" name="bipolar" id="bipolar"><br />
        </span>

        <input type="submit" value="submit">
        <input type="reset" value="Reset">


    </form>

</div>



</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly and did you check the console? *Hint:* `document.getElementsByName` returns an `array`.

Comment: It looks like you're just opening the page `window.open` from the button, so why is it a submit?  Also, what if I check multiple boxes?  I'm confused by this interface in general.  You should make a jsfiddle and be specific about what behavior you're expecting.

Comment: you can only have one true `id="majdep"` on your page, in most browsers it's the very first one, but anything after that won't be included.

Comment: `var majdep1 = document.getElementById("majdep").checked;` and later you do `majdep1.checked` -- you need to remove the `checked` part from either one of them. Now you're practically doing `document.getElementById("majdep").checked.checked`.

Comment: you have too many objects with id=majdep, id should be unique for each object in a page, make this correction then check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in your code

You have referenced `.checked` when you define the variables, and again when you do the if statement.

The following should work

```
function checking()
{
    var frm = document.diaglab;
    // This is incorrect! You have .checked at the end!
    //var majdep1 = document.getElementById("majdep").checked;
    //var bipolar1 = document.getElementsByName("bipolar").checked;
    var majdep1 = document.getElementById("majdep");
    var bipolar1 = document.getElementsById("bipolar");

    if(majdep1.checked == true && bipolar1.checked == true)
    {
        window.alert("possible bipolar disorder");
        window.open("bipolar1.html");
    }else{
        window.alert("please check boxes");
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed the .checked from the variables but no change in the behavior of the script.  I also changed var bipolar1 to document.getElementById rather than ByName.

Comment: Actually guess what major-mann you are awesome because now it is working after I changed the second variable to ById and remove the .checked. it must have taken a second to actually recognize the change. Thanks for your help.  can I ask you another question if I wanted to do the code as getElementsByName what would be the proper format for the array in javascript? If what I am asking makes sense. I tried that way earlier using a for loop and an if statement but it was not working.

Comment: I updated my code to fix that ;) First, you will have issues because you have multiple HTML elements with the same id. You need to fix that. As for getElementsByName, it returns a NodeList of DOM elements . You can get the individual elements by doing a for loop `for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) { console.log(elements[i]); }`

Comment: thanks much I will play around with that a bit. If I dont get the exact behavior I am looking for I will try nested if statements with my current format.

Comment: @ThornPhillips np. Glad to help!